# Firebase sort collection by field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

I have a FireBase Collection ('Messages'):

[image]

I want to sort the collection by specifiec field ('timeStamp').

1. How can I sort it by timeStamp?
2. Is there any way to sort the docs by timeStamp on Firebase instead of sort it while getting snapshot

Comment: As for point 2, I don't think we can do that on the Firebase console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely read the [documentation on ordering query results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data).  Use the `orderBy` method to specify which field should be sorted.

```
firestore.collection("messages").orderBy("timeStamp")
```